# CSS Selector for anchor with href not ending in '#'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display a loading icon on page loading.

I am using HTML, CSS and JS code.

HTML:

```
<div class="loader-icon"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader-icon").fadeOut("slow");
});

$('a').click(function(){
    $(".loader-icon").fadeIn("slow");
})
```

and some CSS to display a loading icon for `div.loader-icon`.

It is working fine if I click on any link which redirects to another page. But it does not work when the link does not redirect to another page. Like when I click on the "Back to Top" icon, the loading icon keeps displaying. It does not fade out.

Suppose:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page/">Page Now</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page/#">Back to Top</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page2/">Page Other</a>
```

It will work for 'Page Other' but not for 'Back to Top'.

So I want to choose a selector for anchors whose hrefs do not end in '#'. Or is there a better way to do the same thing using a different easy trick?

Comment: If you click to go to another page ... then why you need the function to click on the a ? .... it will just refresh your code and show your loader-icon, you just need the load function

Comment: Create  demo that reproduces this

Comment: @DaniP so i need to remove second js code?

Comment: If you don't want that loader at all on the backtoTop .. then remove it , if you reload the page every time and show the load-ico on the initial state, hiding it with the load and fadeout it's enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have to worry about other URLs including a #? If not, you can do your binding on this selector:

```
a:not([href*='#'])
```

That'll only target links that don't include a # in the URL. You can also use this

```
a:not([href^='#'])
```

To target any link that doesn't start with #, and

```
a:not([href$='#'])
```

For any link that doesn't end with #. Hopefully one of these helps!

Comment: As being a CSS-only solution, this would be my answer of choice. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Actually this is a WordPress theme. i think i should remove second js code. because it will create problem with woo commerce add to cart AJAX button. Add to cart link has not # in last.

Comment: You have to go even deeper! a:not([href$='#']):not([href*='cartpagename']) you can add as many stringing :not selectors as you need

Comment: I'd prefer `.not()`, as it is faster and in my opinion more clear than `:not`. Nice explanation of different matches though.

Comment: As far as I know, a jQuery .not would only be faster than a CSS :not if you were using a browser that didn't support CSS :not, specifically lower (8 and below) versions of IE. jQuery .not is probably more readable, though!

Comment: Can you add the 'purpose' as a comment? This is confusing to read, text is above or below the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) with `not()`

```js
 $('a').not('[href$="#"]').on("click", function(e) {
   $(this).toggleClass("active");
   e.preventDefault();
 });
```

```css
.active{ background-color: lime; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Has # at end</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">FOO</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">BAR</a>
```

Could use the [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), but to quote jQuery's recommendation:

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Answer (score -2):

It will not work because you are adding the event for when the window loads, which means you need to refresh the page if you want the icon to fade out.

Add the event also for when you click on the back to top link.

```
<a href="http://example.com/page/#" onclick="myFunct();">Back to Top</a>

...
function myFunct(){
$(".loader-icon").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Also why would you use `onclick`? This isn't the 1990's